# Rest API pagination

Tags: paging

I am using drupal 8.5 and have tried everything people say to get pagination working, but it does not over rest api.  I have 2 news articles, and I set the page value to 1 per page.  I have tried passing in page as a get parameter but still always returns the first news article.

[image: Items per page set to 1]

[image: No matter what value I change page to, it is always first 1]

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have the Full Pager enabled on the View. This will enable paging. Right now you’re only telling the view to show one thing.

Comment: Thank you!  You would be amazed how hard it was to track down this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically change the items per page number?